# Django: validation in models -> is it possible to customize message with data from database that raise the error?

Tags: django, validation

I know there is different way to customize error messages in forms or in models

I customize unique message in my model

```
...
ran_bra = models.CharField("Arm", max_length=1, null=True, blank=True)
pat = models.CharField("Patient number", max_length=8, unique=True, null=True, blank=True,
        validators = [
            RegexValidator(
                regex='^[A-Z]{3}-[0-9]{4}$',
                message= 'L\'identifiant doit être au format XXX-0000',
                code='invalid_participant_id'
            ),
        ],
        error_messages={'unique': u'Ce patient a déjà été randomisé dans le bras X. Veuillez vérifier votre saisie.'},
    )
...
```

but I would like X in the message be replaced by data from database
for example, if user try to enter SMI-0001 that already exist in the database, i would to replace X by ran_bra value of SMI-0001

is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can format strings directly in python. For example:

```py
txt3 = "My name is {}, I'm {}".format("John", 36)
print(txt3)      # My name is John, I'm 36
```

Which, in your case, will be

```py
error_messages={
    'unique': u'Ce patient a déjà été randomisé dans le bras {}. Veuillez vérifier votre saisie.'.format(ran_bra)
},
```

**EDIT**

The long way to do this is to use a function.

```py
def get_string(name):
    return 'Ce patient a déjà été randomisé dans le bras ' + name + '. Veuillez vérifier votre saisie.'

# ...

error_messages = {
    # ...
    'unique': get_string(ran_bra),
}
```

Comment: thanks for replying but it doesn't get value ran_bra... i get result using forms validation in clean method

Comment: The long way to do this is to write another function. Edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this.

```
error_messages={'unique': u'Ce patient a déjà été randomisé dans le bras {}. Veuillez vérifier votre saisie.'.format (your_value)},)
```